# Making AutoMapper reuse previously mapped instances

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I would like AutoMapper to map same object instances `Source` to the same instances of `Target`.

I'm sure that AutoMapper can be configured to do this, but how? I need to convert an object graph A to B, keeping the references between the mapped objects.

For example, this fails:

```
[Fact]
public void Same_instances_are_mapped_to_same_instances()
{
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(config => config.CreateMap<Source, Target>());
    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

    var source = new Source();
    var list = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Target>>(new[] { source, source, source });

    list.Distinct().Should().HaveCount(1);
}

public class Source
{
}

public class Target
{   
}
```

It would like to make this test pass.

Also, please notice that the mapper should "remember" instances mapped during the current `Map` call.

Comment: Your test is inherently wrong, so why would you try to make it pass? `Distinct()` will check for referencial differences hence the failure in test. You could use custom `IEqualityComparer<Target>` to evaluate equality by some custom business logic.

Comment: Sorry, but my test is specifically right and coherent to what I expect. Same instances of A, same instances of B. That's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @Gleb Yes. I need to keep the referential integrity in an object graph. So if A hold a reference to B, mappedA should hold a reference to mappedB.

Comment: Your test is built on the premise of how you think Automapper SHOULD work, not how it DOES work. You might need like custom Automapper logic using converters or custom code altogether.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius AutoMapper can be configured to work like I need. That's what I'm asking: How configure AutoMapper to behave like I want, if possible.

Comment: Set `PreserveReferences`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu where is it? Can you be more explicit? :)  Thanks

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I've found it as an option for `CreateMap`. I'm using inheritance. Should it put it inside the map of the base class or to the maps of the derived classes?

Answer (score 2):

That's the nearest you can get:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(conf => conf.CreateMap<Source, Target>().PreserveReferences());
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var source = new Source();
        var list = new[] { source, source, source };
        var firstRun = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Target>>(list);
        var secondRun = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Target>>(list);

        // Returns two items
        var diffs = firstRun.Concat(secondRun).Distinct();

        foreach (var item in diffs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
        }
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class Target
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This means, that you only get the same item back in case of each call to `mapper.Map()`, but if you call the mapper multiple times, you'll get back new items for each call (which makes sense, otherwise the mapper had to hold references to all given and created instances over it's whole lifetime, which could lead to some serious memory problems).